# How to work with pagination in Unsplash Api in Vanilla Javascriot

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, async-await, dom-events

I am trying to make a website with infinite scroll feature with the photos of the dogs(Unsplash API). But when I call the getphotos() function on the scroll event , it only gives me the images that are on the first page.

I tried to fix this by make 3 different getphotos() function and passing different apiURL with attribute page no. changed. It does work but I don't think it's the best way. I go through the documentation and nothing seems to work . I want to call getphotos() function at a scroll event and each time it should return images from different page .

```
const apiUrl = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?page=1&query=dogs&client_id=${apiKey}&per_page=${per_page}&order_by=relevant;` 

const apiUrl2 = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?page=2&query=dogs&client_id=${apiKey}&per_page=${per_page}&order_by=relevant;`

const apiUrl3 = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?page=3&query=dogs&client_id=${apiKey}&per_page=${per_page}&order_by=relevant;` 



 async function getPhotos(){
    try{
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        photosArray = await response.json();
        console.log(photosArray);
        displayPhotos();
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function getPhotos2(){
    try{
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl2);
        photosArray = await response.json();
        displayPhotos();
        getPhotos3();
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function getPhotos3(){
    try{
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl3);
        photosArray = await response.json();
        displayPhotos();
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```